# How to read email received on a Debian server

Tags: linux, email, debian, forwarding

I have a VPS (virtual private server) running Debian Linux. When I login using PuTTY the console shows - "You have mail"

I have no idea on how to retrieve this email. Which software do I need to install? Which steps to follow?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just type `mail`, it is the most basic way to read the mail. It should be installed by default on a Debian system, it comes from the mailutils package. Read the man page or type `?` to figure out commands to use.

But there are better ways to read the mail. As noted earlier, `mailx` is an improved version. Even more user-friendly are [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/), [cone](http://www.courier-mta.org/cone/cone00index.html) and [(al)pine](http://www.washington.edu/pine/). All of these are packaged by Debian and can be installed by apt-get

Comment: `(al)pine` is cosy as `pico` or `nano`, so if you feel ok with the latters go with the first.

Answer (score 8):

I find the mail program difficult to use. The mail is stored in a flat file, so I use `vi /var/spool/mail/user` and manage it there.

Answer (score 6):

```
/var/mail/user
```

**or**

```
/var/spool/mail/user
```

Comment: don`t forget to read with **CAT** 

     cat /var/mail/root
     cat /var/spool/mail/root

Comment: This suggestion has been made before. Could you expand on what you are doing differently?

Answer (score 1):

[**mailx**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailx) is present by default on most systems. Type `mailx` to invoke it. Read the manpages to understand how to navigate the mailx interface.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of mail client to be configured. I use alpine as it has basic text-GUI
and I used it somewhere previously and I am customed to it. Very easy to use, configurable, etc. btw. One way to manage is fetchmail:ing to some other location, if system has mail server installed. Plain .forward file with your mail address in it /home/dir is an option too! Don't create a loop, though!